# How to change row major to column major or vice versa in fragment/vertex shader?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader

I am having a array of pixels which is in row major or column major depending on the configuration and I don't have any handle on it prior to receiving it.

So, for me it's easy to shift  in javascript code but I am not getting any idea on how to shift the same in OpenGL Shaders.

Here's the javascript code to shift :

```
var MBytes = new Uint16Array(rows*cols);
var k = 0;
var p = 0;
var pos = 0;
for(var i=0;i<rows;i=i+1){
    k = i*cols;
    p = i;
    for(var j=0;j<cols;j=j+1){
        pos = k + j;
        MBytes[pos] = incomingPixels[p];
        p = p + rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just rotate the image? isn't that what you want? draw the image rotated 90 degrees using any standard method

Comment: @Rabbid76 Swizzling isn't working for me as the image is just not flipped as you can see in the snippet above

Comment: @gman I need to shift the pixels as per the above code, currently I am able to see some wrong image with jumbled pixels and after using the above cpu side snippet I am able to see the perfect image but I am wondering on shall I change something to the vertex shader which runs one time or fragment shader that runs for each pixel

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think you have certainly given some hope .. Let me try that now

Comment: Can anyone of you put your ideas as answer so that I can accept. Your ideas helped me achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rotate the actual pixel data if you can avoid it - that's horribly expensive. Just change your texture coordinates so that the logical access is rotated.

Normally for OpenGL ES texture coordinates bottom left is 0,0, top right is 1,1. I if you need to rotate left by 90 degrees on screen then rotate right by 90 degrees in coordinate space (so top left in your application is 0,0, and that will be displayed at the bottom left on screen).

If you need to encode a Y-flip too, then just swap the Y coordinates.

Comment: Yes am doing the same . Thanks